# Can I find all the resources js, css, etc ... in the cache for a specific url using the Java instructions?

Tags: java, browser-cache, cache-control, cloudflare

For example I'd like find all resource with "cf-cache-status" HIT for a specific url. It is possible?
[cf-cache-status resource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Phw1q.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clear cache for all possible query parameter url for specific url - CloudFlare](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42579658/clear-cache-for-all-possible-query-parameter-url-for-specific-url-cloudflare)