# Clear cache for all possible query parameter url for specific url - CloudFlare

Tags: caching, curl, cache-control, cloudflare, clear-cache

How can I find all urls with every possible query parameters? 
There is specific curl command launched with terminal for do this?

For example i must clear cache for url: example.com/, example.com/lang=en, example.com/lang=es, ...

Answer (score -1):

If you pay for higher plans you can purge cache with wildcards, such as `example.com/lang=*`.

Otherwise you'll have to enter each page in the list. You might be better off clearing the entire cache.